# Is JAX-WS using serverside Stubs (Skeletons) for communication?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

As far as I know, the predecessor of JAX-WS (JAX-RPC) was using a
Client-Stub (Proxy) <--> Server-Skeleton (also called serverside stub, or Tie) system for the communication between Client and Service.

But if I am reading on the topic of communication in JAX-WS, I can't find anything relating Skeletons, serverside stubs, or Ties. Neither can I find anyone writing, that JAX-WS no longer needs skeletons. My researches only lead me to JAX-RPC topics, java rmi, or WSDL to Java approaches (SEI-Skeletons, but i don't think that are the skeletons I am looking for). But something in JAX-WS has to handle and steer the work of taking the SOAP-request, marshalling/unmarshalling it with JAXB and giving the parameters to the Methods of the Service Implementation.

Does anyone know, if JAX-WS is still using skeletons/ties on the server side and how they are created (with link to a source would be cool)? And if they are not used anymore, how is their work done?

I hope, my english isn't too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The skeleton is still there but you can't see it.

The "server stub" in the picture below is the skeleton. It is created based on your annotated classe (@WebService), when the application is deployed.

It is still responsible in parsing the content, but now using JAXB.

Take a look at this link:

http://qallme.sourceforge.net/docs/sec_CreatingAWSImplementationSkeleton.html

[image]

Comment: So they are still used, thank you. I have one question to the example in your link: For me it looks, like there is just discribed, how to write a Service Endpoint Implementation and with "Skeleton" they only mean a hull without actual use, in contrast to a server stub, that is actually doing quite much. But if I understood you correctly, this class would be used to generate the server stub during deployment. Is that generation done by JAX-WS, or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to a trustworthy resource to sustain my answer (like a book). Until now no luck. If I don't find I will erase my answer.

Comment: Your answer helped me in any case. I just wanted to be sure that I didn't misunderstood the example in the link.